# Using request animation frame in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requestanimationframe

I'm reading [this article](https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe-with-react-hooks/) and I'm not sure I understand how the final hook works.

Here is the code:

```js
const useAnimationFrame = (callback) => {
  const requestRef = useRef();
  const previousTimeRef = useRef();

  const animate = (time) => {
    if (previousTimeRef.current !== undefined) {
      const deltaTime = time - previousTimeRef.current;
      callback(deltaTime);
    }
    previousTimeRef.current = time;
    requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    return () => cancelAnimationFrame(requestRef.current);
  }, []);
}
```

and used for example in this way:

```js
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

useAnimationFrame((deltaTime) => {
  setCount((prevCount) => {
    return prevCount + 1;
  });
});
```

Ok, the goal is have a number value that is incremented every frame.

I can explain what is happens running this code:

1. the component create a local state with `useState(0)`
2. then the `useAnimationFrame` hook is called using  this callback as parameter:

   ```js
   (deltaTime) => {
     setCount((prevCount) => {
       return prevCount + 1;
     });
   }
   ```

the function takes a number as input and increment ste state value of one each time it is called.

3. `useAnimationFrame` is a function that takes another function as a parameter (a callback). It creates two refs. At the first time it is executed (because of the `[]`) it calls the `useEffect`. It saves in `requestRef.current` the timestamp the `requestAnimationFrame` returns. The `requestRef.current` calls the `animate` function that computes the delta time between the request animation frames (the previous and the current) and then call the callback with this value so it calls the `setCount`. Then it updates the current refs values and recall the `requestAnimationFrame`.

So the cycle should be:

```
component 
  > count = 0
useAnimationFrame             <--------------+
  > requestRef = ?                           |
  > previousTimeRef = ?                      |
    useEffect                                |
      animate                                |
        > deltaTime = delta#1                |
        > count = 1                          |
        > previousTimeRef.current = time#1   |
        > requestRef.current = time#2 -------+
      > requestRef.current = timestamp#1
```

Am I wrong?

Comment: useEffect should be dependent on the callback Fn. 
In case your callback fn depends on e.g. external values from other hooks it will not get updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be helpful to track the function signatures of `requestAnimationFrame` and `cancelAnimationFrame`.

[requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) takes a single argument, a callback function. The callback function itself receives a single timestamp argument (DOMHighResTimeStamp)

[cancelAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame) takes a single argument, the `id` of the `requestAnimationFrame` which you want to cancel.

So `time` in the `animate` callback function is the single argument received via the api, `a DOMHighResTimeStamp similar to the one returned by performance.now(), indicating the point in time when requestAnimationFrame() starts to execute callback functions.`

```js
 const animate = (time) => {
```

This is a check to see if the hook has already run 1x. If it has, update the parent React scope with the new time minus the previous time

```js
    if (previousTimeRef.current !== undefined) {
      const deltaTime = time - previousTimeRef.current;
      callback(deltaTime);
    }
```

Once the hook is confirmed as having run, save the `DOMHighResTimeStamp` for future calculations

```js
    previousTimeRef.current = time;
```

After this, it gets a bit interesting and I am not sure this is best approach. It may even be a bug. The code sets a new listener and updates the `ref` with the latest id, based on the result of a new invocation.

Just from reading the code, I am not sure the original listener ever gets `cancelled`. I suspect it is not.

```js
    /// this is an id
    requestRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

I don't have access to a running version, but I would suggest removing the `requestRef.current` altogether and see if the clean-up happens as expected when the `useEffect` clean-up happens e.g.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    return () => cancelAnimationFrame(id);
  }, []);
```

This will also simplify the embedded `refs` as well to make reading a bit more clear.

Comment: `requestRef.current` is updated on every loop so that whenever the `useEffect` runs its cleanup function, it cancels the current `requestAnimationFrame` and not the first one made.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` calls itself in a loop, that a standard practice in JS animation.

Comment: Perhaps it is better stated - the `useEffect` in this code does not run/re-render on every `requestAnimationFrame`. While there is no re-render, the `requestAnimationFrame` loop will continue to iterate. When it does re-render, the clean-up function will unregister the `id` and init a new animation frame loop. Thus, the `requestRef.current` is superfluous and adds unnecessary complexity.

Comment: I'd love to see a working proof of concept of this, because it doesn't match my mental model of how this works. Each call to `requestAnimationFrame` generates a *new* id. Cancelling with the 1st id after a bunch of iterations will have no effect.